# How to load location by utc offset

Tags: go, timezone

I want to load location via UTC offset, e.g.

```
func main() {
    L, err := time.LoadLocation("UTC+8")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(L)
}
```

The code panics: `panic: unknown time zone UTC+8`

How can I get the location object by UTC offset (NOT local nor UTC, but another location), without having to specify it in IANA Time Zone format, such as "America/New_York"

My purpose is simple: I have a web server running in a fixed location, which I can get the local time easily.  Now I want to do time calculation based on the location of visitor (which is sent over by a url parameter, e.g. `http://myserver.com/do_something?timezone=-8`).

Comment: If you are doing things correctly, you should not care what location your server is in. 
 UTC applies everywhere.  Just get the UTC time, not the server's local time.  The server's local time should be irrelevant to your application.  Also, keep in mind that an offset only applies for a single point in time, where a time zone represents *all* offsets that might be applicable.  `America/New_York`  is UTC-5 during standard time, and UTC-4 for during daylight saving time.  See also "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: @MattJohnson I want to display time in local time. just consider the use case that you want to buy a film ticket in Shanghai two days later, which you are now in London and is flying there tonight. You want the time to be local time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it:

```
time.FixedZone(name string, offset int)
```

This will create a Location with given name (which is not important) and the offset.